# Forward Converter Snubbing Optimization/Alternative

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, solid-state-devices

I'm working on a single-switch forward converter with a reset winding and synchronous operation.  The basic specifications are as follows:

- **12.0 +- 5% V** output voltage
- **22-36 V** input voltage
- **96 W / 8 A** nominal operating condition
- **300 kHz** switching frequency

The following circuit is a simplification of my full-transient model which includes my PWM controller, compensation network, slow start circuit, dead-time generators, current sense XFMR etc..  What I'm highlighting in the model is the well understood phenomenon of voltage overshoot and ringing on the secondary switch node (cathode of D5).  The converter that I've implemented (for academic purposes) in real life matches the simulation and to-be discussed issue very closely.

So far I have only inserted the synchronous FET that is in parallel with D5, the free-wheeling diode.  I am keeping it present, despite grounding the gate, because it has implications on the *Vsws* node parasitic capacitance and overshoot condition.  The real implementation has a safety gate zener, a gate resistor, ect..

At low output power levels I can regulate just fine, and all other switch nodes are fairly well behaved.

[image]

**Problem:** The amount of overshoot on the node labeled *Vsws* becomes unacceptable above 25 Watts output power for components Q1 and D5, which are 200 Volt rated.  Nominal voltage on *Vsws* is 60V, due to a turns ratio of 2 on the XFMR.

**Problem Causation Theory (*I Think*):** When the primary switch turns on (shown above by S1), D5 attempts to turn off and D2 attempts to turn on.  However, the reverse recovery current of D5 briefly delays it's turn off and makes it so *Vsws* is at a low potential during this time period.  L2 (the leakage inductance of the XFMR) becomes energized with a current that is far from the average value of L1 (the filter inductor).  When D5 does turn off, the current through the leakage inductor becomes that of L1 due to the series connection.  The di/dt value through L2 creates the voltage spike which rings at a frequency driven by it and the capacitance of Q1, D5, and other parasitics.

This phenomenon is well described and supported by [EEtimes](https://www.eetimes.com/power-tip-snubbing-the-forward-converter/), [TI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qy3O7OZFeGg), and this [snubber paper](http://educypedia.karadimov.info/library/slup100.pdf) by a Philip C. Todd.

All resources I've found recommend implementing a simple RC snubber to rectify the issue, as shown in the schematic.  In simulation and on the implemented converter I have used the snubber technique that inserts pure capacitance until the ringing frequency is halved to deduce the parasitic capacitance.  Then an optimal snubber capacitance of 3 times this values is used and a resistance calculated by 1/(2pi * f_ring * C_para).

While this strategy has consistently eliminated the ringing on the referenced switch node, the initial overshoot has only reduced by 20-30V, and as my output power climbs, so does the overshoot, until part breakdown is a concern.  **Perhaps the reverse recovery time increases with temperature, and the energy injected into the leakage inductor increases with it.**

[image]

From the snubbing experiments I can confirm the leakage inductance to be around 600 nF, and my parasitic capacitance on *Vsws* to be around 700pF.  These seem to be relatively high values, but due to the structure of the project, I can't reduce them too much further.

Removing Q1 completely and re-snubbing leads to less overshoot, but the same general trend that makes overshoot unacceptable at higher power levels.  Actually driving  the gate of Q1, with conservative dead time yields even worse overshoot at primary switch turn on.  I have tried multiple diodes for D5 and FETs for Q1 with no avail:

- A smaller 100V Shotkey diode to minimize reverse recovery (best performance as of yet) (NKVTSA4100ET3G)
- The beefier 200V Shotkey used for initial testing (SBRD10200TR)
- An ultra-fast 200V diode (FFD10UP20S)

I have noticed one interesting thing in the simulation that concerns me.  It seems that that the body diode in the Q1, which should not be the main current carrying path due to D5's lower forward voltage, is taking the brunt of the reverse recovery current.  The graphs below show that Q1's body diode does get forward biased, and shares some current, before making a large contribution to the voltage spike mechanism.

[image]

[image]

**Questions**

1. Is there a way to design an RC snubber that is *critically damped* such that the 2nd order system has no zero overshoot, but takes on more loss.
2. Is there an alternative snubber design I can use to reduce overshoot?  I have tried simulation an RCD snubber with poor results.  This question is really what drove me to perform this write up, as all resources I have found *only* detail an RC snubber.
3. If I had a zener diode to hard-clamp the node at around 100V, will i suffer supreme inefficiency?  I'm not sure if the energy will very quickly be dissipated out of the system such that the zener power is low or not.  Is this a bad idea?
4. Could this be a layout or component problem such that an extra parasitic inductance element is dominating. Even in simulation I cannot reduce overshoot when i have similar part models.
5. If the FET body diode is driving the recovery mechanism, and leading to higher spikes than necessary, how would I prevent this?  Even with the FET removed i still run into problems, so I'm not sure I'd totally like to pursue this.
6. I have read a bit about current snubbers in series with diodes to reduce reverse reverse recovery time, but have been forwarded that the bead inductors required are poor at handling power.  Are there any reliable circuits to do this?

Comment: Welcome. What diode +RC snubber designs have you studied? Some research would help narrow down the number of questions your asking, which implies you have little to no experience with switching power supplies. Do some research and answer some of your own question. After that we will try to help you.

Comment: @Sparky256 Hello, thanks for the response.  Would you be able to point me in the direction of a good snubber resource.  The overwhelming majority of resources I used for the converter design went with a simple RC snubber.  I'm looking for a good solid textbook and not an online app note or white page.  I know there were a lot of questions but they are all inter-related, and the reason I'm posting is that my many of attempts/sims/experiments have taken me to those roadblocks.